# Visual Studio 2019 not showing emulators or connected devices (and restart ADB server button grayed out)

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

Visual Studio 2017 won't list connected devices or running emulators, and the "Restart ADB Server" button is grayed out. Despite this, opening the ADB Command Prompt and running "adb devices" successfully lists everything.

All updates applied, SDK manager shows everything as up to date, etc, VS fully updated, no change. Restarting machine and VS has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

The solution ended up being to open Xamarin preferences in VS (Tools -> Options -> Xamarin) and locate the Android SDK path. I deleted the SDK folder and VS prompted to re-install the SDK. Upon completion of reinstall, my devices showed and were successfully listed and I was able to debug. I believe the SDK was out of date, but Visual Studio failed to recognize this or doesn't seem to have an update feature set up for this.

Hopefully this saves someone else the hours I spent trying to get debugging working...